# Are there plans for an Ubuntu One mobile client for Symbian Belle?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Will the Ubuntu One mobile client be released for symbian belle?

Comment: The N9 version I wrote is in Python and QML. It may be possible to port that to Symbian; if so, I'd be happy to talk to someone who is able to do it. Glad you like the N9 version :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no plans to release Ubuntu One for the Symbian platform.